# SQL Search running slowly, only in browser

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server

I've got a small search function on a page of mine.

```
IF LEN(@firstName) < 1 OR @firstName IS NULL
set @firstName = '%'    


IF LEN(@lastName) < 1 OR @lastName IS NULL
set @lastName = '%'

IF LEN(@carrierId) < 1 OR @carrierId IS NULL
set @carrierId = '%'


IF LEN(@worksheetId) < 1 OR @worksheetId IS NULL
set @worksheetId = '%'  

SELECT TOP 1000 m.[Guid], m.WorksheetID, d.FirstName, d.LastName, m.VersionNum FROM Main m
INNER JOIN utl_Driver d ON m.DriverID = d.DriverID
    WHERE d.FirstName LIKE @firstName
    AND d.LastName LIKE @lastName
    AND d.CarrierID LIKE @carrierId
    AND m.WorksheetID LIKE @worksheetId
    AND m.Deleted = 0
    AND d.VersionNum = (SELECT MAX(VersionNum)
                            FROM Main B WHERE b.WorksheetID = m.WorksheetID)
    ORDER BY m.DateTimeStart DESC;
```

It's lightning quick in SQL Server Management Studio, but performs oddly when the stored procedure is called by my ASP.Net application. Searching via LastName is usually quick, but FirstName or WorksheetID times out. Moreover, erasing the 'm.Deleted = 0' check makes all queries execute very quickly, but I obviously need that check. Any advice?

Comment: Do you have an index on `Main.Deleted`?

Comment: Stored procs often get a different query plan than when you just execute the query in SSMS. It will usually try to use an index that is actually detrimental to the query (its silly). Are you running the query or the sproc in SSMS?

Comment: No - Main.[Guid] has a clustered index. Nothing else is indexed. And Joe: I'm running the sproc in SSMS, where it runs quickly regardless of whether or not I'm checking m.Deleted. It's only when I call the sproc through the application that it hangs.

Comment: Well, add an index to Main.Deleted and retry

Comment: See [Slow in the Application, Fast in SSMS? Understanding Performance Mysteries](http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html) for some explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would you please try as below: thanks for your time.

```
DECLARE @whereCondition NVARCHAR(1000)
SET @whereCondition = ' WHERE 1 = 1 '

IF @firstName <> '' AND @firstName IS NOT NULL
    SET @whereCondition = @whereCondition + ' AND d.FirstName LIKE  ''' + @firstName + ''''

IF @lastName <> '' AND @lastName IS NOT NULL
    SET @whereCondition = @whereCondition + ' AND  d.LastName LIKE  ''' + @lastName + ''''

IF @carrierId <> '' AND @carrierId<> 0 AND @carrierId IS NOT NULL
    SET @whereCondition = @whereCondition + ' AND  d.CarrierID LIKE  ''' + @carrierId + ''''

IF @worksheetId <> '' AND @worksheetId<> 0  AND @worksheetId IS NOT NULL
    SET @whereCondition = @whereCondition + ' AND  m.WorksheetID LIKE  ''' + @worksheetId + ''''

SET @whereCondition = @whereCondition + ' AND  m.Deleted = 0'
SET @whereCondition = @whereCondition + ' AND  d.VersionNum = (SELECT MAX(VersionNum)
                            FROM Main B WHERE b.WorksheetID = m.WorksheetID) '

EXEC('SELECT TOP 1000 m.[Guid], m.WorksheetID, d.FirstName, d.LastName, m.VersionNum FROM Main m
       INNER JOIN utl_Driver d ON m.DriverID = d.DriverID '
       + @whereCondition +
       ' ORDER BY m.DateTimeStart DESC; ' )
```

Answer (score 1):

this query will never preform well. you are doing table scans across 4 different fields.
I also don't see any paging in the query which means all results are returned. this will be a problem with large set of data.

introduce webforms and now you have viewstate. a grid/list view will store the entire result set in viewstate (even if you enable client paging).

these are 3 main bottlenecks I see.
1. poor query performance due to "like" operator
2. result set may be too large
3. webforms view state

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Jason. What would you do in order to optimize this? Paging functionality isn't really an option in the context of this search - it isn't intended to dump, clearly, more than 1000 records. I indexed the 'Deleted' field and it's running MUCH quicker through the application, but I'd definitely like to make it as fast as possible! Any advice you may have in terms of optimization would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: if you want full text search then implement full text search, SQL Server had full text indexing, or you could introduce Lucene.Net to manage the document indexing.

as it stands now the result set is not bound, so the query could return 100K+ records. it all depends on the amount of data in the db.

since "like" preforms a table scan the query performance will degrade over time and more data is added to the db.